# Plugin requires Maven version 3.0 in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] Error resolving version for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin': Plugin requires Maven version 3.0
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
```

Comment: You're probably using Maven 2 (use `mvn -v` to show the version). You need to download Maven 3 first.

Comment: As the message says you need Maven 3+ ...